# Running sample google map in api tutorial

Tags: google-maps

I have copied the html from the sample map from: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml. I simply copied code into text editor and saved as html and run in IE and Firefox but no map showed.Any advice please

thanks
Ian

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the google maps tutorial work on my pc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971379/why-doesnt-the-google-maps-tutorial-work-on-my-pc)

Answer (score 0):

You need this file also:

```
<link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

[Google's sample on my server](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml.html)

or include this in its place:

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map-canvas, #map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
}

@media print {
  html, body {
    height: auto;
  }

  #map_canvas {
    height: 650px;
  }
}

#panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -180px;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
</style>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. The css link is already there. This is the code:

Comment: couldn't add code, file too long.This is the link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml

Comment: Is your copy of that code on google's server?  Did you copy the css file to the equivalent location on _your_ server (or local computer)?  The example(s) in the documentation work fine for me when I do that (actually I usually just replace the link with the style tags as above).  BTW - please don't post code in the comments, it is better to edit your question to add it (it should have been there already...).

Comment: thanks, sorry about editing error. As you may have guessed I am new to html/javascript. I just copied the code to notepad on my pc and renamed to html.I added your inline css and all works fine. Thank you.